# clinfo versus sudo clinfo

Tags: 20.04, gpu, opencl

I run a program and receive an error indicating that a GPU device is not found. I guess the source of issue is below. How I can make `clinfo` give same result as `sudo clinfo`?

The result of `clinfo` is:

```
Number of platforms                               0
```

The result of `sudo clinfo` is:

```
  Platform Name                                   Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     Intel(R) Graphics [0x4c8a]
  Device Vendor                                   Intel(R) Corporation
  Device Vendor ID                                0x8086
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 3.0 NEO 
  Driver Version                                  21.42.021270
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.2 
  Device Type                                     GPU
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your user is not part of the `render` group.

Try `sudo adduser $USER render`